# How to combine 3 different line plots in one plot

Tags: r, plot, line

Suppose I have 3 age groups: Infants, Adults and Elderly.
In each group, I have 3 subjects. For each age group, I'm plotting a combined line plot:

```
p1 <- plot(infants$`8838`, type="l", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 0.90), xlim = c(0,3000))
       lines(infants$`9048`, typr = "l", col="red")
       lines(infants$`9108`, typr = "l", col="green")
p2 <- plot(adol$`8804`, type="l", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 0.90), xlim = c(0,3000))
    lines(adol$`12291`, typr = "l", col="red")
    lines(adol$`12623`, typr = "l", col="green")
p3 <- plot(old$`10341`, type="l", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 0.90), xlim = c(0,3000))
    lines(old$`10690`, typr = "l", col="red")
    lines(old$`10896`, typr = "l", col="green")
```

Now I need to combine all that three plots in one graph. 
Could anyone please help me find an answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question based on these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). (Opinion based) Maybe do it with `ggplot2`? It seems "easier" to use.

Comment: Before all your commands, type `op  <- par(mfrow=c(1,3))`. At the very end, type `par(op)`. Place all your plotting commands inside those two commands. If you want the 3 plots on top of each other, replace `c(1,3)` with `c(3,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `par(mfrow = c(1, 3))` before any `plot()` command to section the display. After that each call to `plot()` will use a new section. See `?par` for details.